# Git folder rename keep failing - permission denied

Tags: git

I am getting this error message from GIT:

```
rename folder from X to Y failed, should I try again?
```

What I tried so far:
- Tortoise git
- Git UI
- Git UI with administrator permissions.
- Restart PC
- Git Bash with administrator permissions.

Still the same thing - fatal: renaming folder failed: Permission denied.

**UPDATE 3**

I changed all file permissions to Everyone

```
icacls "c:\projects\TRUNK\PRINT_FILES11\" /remove:d Everyone /grant:r Everyone:(OI)(CI)F /T
```

this is the result of the command:

```
....
processed file: c:\projects\TRUNK\PRINT_FILES11\maven-compiler-    plugin\compile\default-compile\inputFiles.lst
processed file: c:\projects\TRUNK\PRINT_FILES11\maven-compiler-    plugin\testCompile\default-testCompile
processed file: c:\projects\TRUNK\PRINT_FILES11\maven-compiler-plugin\testCompile\default-testCompile\inputFiles.lst
Successfully processed 77226 files; Failed processing 0 files
C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

still getting same thing.

my Tortoise git version is

```
TortoiseGit 2.8.0.0 (C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin)  
git version 2.18.0.windows.1 (  
    C:\Program Files\Git\bin;   
    C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\;   
    C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\etc\gitconfig;   
    C:\ProgramData\Git\config)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What does Windows show you as the permissions on the file? What happens if you copy the file outside the directory to someplace else, but with the same name, and then try the same rename on the copy, but with ordinary windows commands?

Answer (score 9):

Try to make sure there's nothing going on in the folder you want to rename that would typically keep you from being able to rename the folder via GUI (e.g., having a file open in another program).

I had this problem just now and fixed it after reading [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/430655) on unix.stackexchange.com.

In my case, I happened to have the working directory open in a File Explorer window (I'm on Windows 10 Home 64-bit).

Comment: For example, also close IntelliJ.

Comment: There are (or used to be) programs and tools that would show you which processes have a file open (in the past, one was called wholockme--I don't know if that still works with the latest Windows).  Anyone know of any good current tools for this or if that tool still works?

Comment: @TimLudwinski Very old bump but File Locksmith (part of [PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys)) is a great replacement.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the folder to rename contained subfolders that were not git controlled (the bin and obj folders).
Moving these folders elsewhere, git renaming, and moving the folders back, solved the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Solved my issue by creating a "temp" folder, moving "bin" and "obj" folders there, executing `git mv` and then moving these folders back to the renamed folder.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue in a simple way, you can do the following two steps below using git bash:

1. Rename "PRINT_FILES11" to "tmp"
2. Rename "tmp" to "Prnt_f"

Here is the command how to do this(worked for windows):

```
git mv PRINT_FILES11 tmp
git mv tmp Prnt_f
```